# Ground Plane Method

Tags: pcb, raspberry-pi, ground, ground-plane

I am designing a PCB to handle some modifications as a stepping stone from a well designed pcb from professionals to what my modifications need to be.

I have poured ground on top and bottom and joined them with vias throughout the board.
[image]

Question: Should I be including these ground planes, and if so, is the clearance between our through holes on the 2x20 pin connector okay? What width and clearance values are needed and is there a rule of thumb for clearance distance with the ground planes and traces/ through holes? I know the software handles this, but the clearance values can be set. How does one determine the correct clearance values?
[image]
Notes:
Every signal will be 5v pull ups on the pins other than the 5V pin 02 and SGND pin 39.

The floating pins are unused. The signal net traces to the right are 5V encoder pins.

The Nets 25- 28 is our POE pair signals going from a 4 pin connector (wire to board) and a 4 pin connector to our main board. This is for test and the other board has 0 ohm resistors that will be removed if it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General comment:

I do not mind top and bottom Ground Planes, as long as I do not have to account for changed impedances. You did the right thing by placing the stitchers. Every 1/2" to 1" is sufficient.Some folks use them to work as shielding planes but then you have to make sure you run no current through them.
This said, if you have a through hole component like you do with the headers, make sure you know what thermals' size to use, as the soldering could be difficult due to 3 planes sucking the heat out of the solder.

Personally, on external layers I try to have no less than 7 mils of clearance due to having experience with underetching with 5 mils; 5 mils is OK on the internal layers.

Otherwise, your creepage and clearance depend on your electrical and safety requirements. If you have 12V of unlimited power with 7 mils clearance on an external layer, this is not good. I think you are OK in your case.

Again, I suggest no less than 7 mils clearance around any pad on the external layer and watching your thermals for good solderability, the rest is less important.

All in all,

Answer (score 2):

As always in engineering, the answer is a tradeoff. The tighter the clearance you use in a design, the more you can cram in, but the more it will cost. When it comes to clearance for suitable isolation, then something like the Saturn PCB toolkit is a good place to start. For 0-15V signals on a component pin/pad, it says you need at least 0.13mm (5.1 mil) conductor spacing. I think its numbers correspond to IPC-2221B so it's a reasonable starting point as a minimum clearance.

Personally, I usually start at 0.15 mm/6 mil and go down if I need tighter gaps. This is my starting point as it's above the clearance needed on component pads up to 100V, and generally, I think it's the bottom of prices. I don't think you get much cheaper from PCB fabs for wanting 8 or 10 mil clearance, but that's anecdotal from me. 
 
Alternatively, you could look at your finest pitch part, find the clearance between the pads, and use that. Any more clearance and you wouldn't be able to place your parts but any less and you'll be spending money for specs you don't need. You should round down to the nearest mil's worth of clearance.
Or if you were getting your boards made from a fab like OSHPark with a fixed minimum spec, you'd find that spec and use it for all your projects. FAB input is important for this sort of thing.

I've only ever used one or two clearance values in my work personally when I've had some high (>100V) voltages involved. It is worth noting that the clearance you need for pins/pads is much greater than you need for traces side by side so if you were *really* cramming the routing in you might use as low as 0.05mm for your clearance on the internal layer traces, but 0.13mm around component pads.